# Errors persisting after recovering YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

We’re trying to do a postmortem on an issue we hit in our cluster. It looks like one of our 3 nodes went down and the other two were unable to process requests until it came back. Looking over the logs, I see this message a lot from both before and during the outage:

```
W0810 00:46:40.740047 3997211 leader_election.cc:285] T 00000000000000000000000000000000 P f65e3577ff4e42a3b935c36a99be1fb9 [CANDIDATE]: Term 7 pre-election: Tablet error from VoteRequest() call to peer df99aaa63d14414785aa9842fcf2fdc1: Invalid argument (yb/tserver/service_util.h:75): RequestConsensusVote: Wrong destination UUID requested. Local UUID: 55065b84a4df41ffac5841463871778a. Requested UUID: df99aaa63d14414785aa9842fcf2fdc1
I0810 00:46:40.740072 3997211 leader_election.cc:244] T 00000000000000000000000000000000 P f65e3577ff4e42a3b935c36a99be1fb9 [CANDIDATE]: Term 7 pre-election: Election decided. Result: candidate lost.
```

We, unfortunately, lost the logs from the node that went down due to a data loss issue on our side.Also, I’m actually still seeing the messages above even though the cluster has recovered so it looks like we’re still in a state.

What does this mean and does it prevent the cluster from electing a new leader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yb-master process recently running on `prod-db-us-2` has a UUID of `55065b84a4df41ffac5841463871778a`  but the yb-master process running on `prod-db-us-1` believes that the yb-master on `prod-db-us-2` has a UUID of `df99aaa63d14414785aa9842fcf2fdc1`. This seems like a configuration issue.
My guess is that `55065b84a4df41ffac5841463871778a` was originally `df99aaa63d14414785aa9842fcf2fdc1`. The UUID could change if the data directory is wiped.
You had a loss of data incident on `prod-db-us-2` about a month and a half ago so that’s probably when the UUID changed.

Here’s the official documentation for replacing a failed master: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/troubleshoot/cluster/replace_master/

Alternatively, you could wipe 55065b84a4df41ffac5841463871778a and create a new yb-master using gflag `instance_uuid_override` to force it to initialize with uuid df99aaa63d14414785aa9842fcf2fdc1.